# Why do I have to re-assign the links and nodes when updating the d3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795), where everybody leads me to, the code writer re-assigns the var `link` and `node` in the `start()` method. I don't really understand why. Since both snipets are identical, I'll focus on one:

```
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
link.exit().remove();
```

*Q 1: `link` is already asigned as `var link = svg.selectAll(".link");` meaning `link` contains all DOM Elements in the `svg` container classed `.link`. This selection may be empty at the start of the example, but why does he re-asign it to all links in the force?*
*Q 2: Why does he return the `d.source.id` and the `d.target.id` property? Is this necessary to identify the link?*
*Q 3: Other manipulations (such as add color to a link) would be done like this?*

```
link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link").style("stroke", function(d) { 
    return d.color;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Like you said initially its empty  `var link = svg.selectAll(".link");`
But when the data comes in the `start` function this variable holds all the current links.

**Question 2**

Q 2: Why does he return the d.source.id and the d.target.id property? Is this necessary to identify the link?

```
link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
```

This is done to uniquely identify a link. The function returns a unique id of a link which is a combination of source and target id.
Needed so that the exit function knows after intersection which link need to be removed.

**Question 3**

Q 3: Other manipulations (such as add color to a link) would be done like this?

```
link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link").style("stroke", function(d) { 
    return d.color;
});
```

Yes! if the link data has a variable color in it.
Something like this `{source: a, target: b, color:"red"}`
code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPhfyEIN311Xpnj1aycQ?p=preview)

Hope this helps!